# How to use RANK to Group Matched Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ranking

Long Story short.  I have data that I'm trying to identify duplicate records by address.  The address can be matched on the `[Address]` or `[Remit_Address]` fields.
I use a JOIN and UNION to get the records, but I need the matched records to appear with each other in the results.

I can't sort by any of the existing fields, so a typical 'ORDER BY' won't work.  I looked into `RANK` as suggested by someone and it looks like it might work, but I don't know how to do the Partition, and I think the Order gives me the same issue with `ORDER BY`.

If RANK is not the best option I'm open to other ideas.  The goal ultimately is to group the matched records someway.

- SSMS 18
- SQL Server 2019

Here is the setup:

```
-- Output Table
CREATE TABLE [dupecheck] (
  [id] int identity(1, 1), 
  [Data Area] varchar(255), 
  [Supplier_No] varchar(255), 
  [Name] varchar(255), 
  [Address] varchar(255), 
  [City] varchar(255), 
  [State] varchar(255), 
  [Zip] varchar(255), 
  [Country] varchar(255), 
  [Remit_Address] varchar(255), 
  [Remit_City] varchar(255), 
  [Remit_State] varchar(255), 
  [Remit_Zip] varchar(255), 
  [Remit_Country] varchar(255), 
)


CREATE TABLE [sample_data] (
    [Supplier_No]           varchar(255),
    [Name]                  varchar(255),
    [Address]               varchar(255),
    [City]                  varchar(255),
    [State]                 varchar(255),
    [Zip]                   varchar(255),
    [Country]               varchar(255),
    [Remit_Address]         varchar(255),
    [Remit_City]            varchar(255),
    [Remit_State]           varchar(255),
    [Remit_Zip]             varchar(255),
    [Remit_Country]         varchar(255),
    [cleanAddress]          varchar(255),
    [cleanRemit_Address]    varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT [suppliers_pk] PRIMARY KEY ([Supplier_No])
)

INSERT INTO [sample_data] VALUES
    ('1039104','Geez Companies','100 Aero Hudson Rd','Streetsboro','OH','44241','','100 Aero Hudson Road','Streetsboro','OH','44241','USA','100 Aero Hudson Rd','100 Aero Hudson Rd'),
    ('1218409','SouthWestern Medical','100 West Balor Ave','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','100 W Balor Ave','SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave'),
    ('1243789','SouthWestern Medical','100 West Balor Ave','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','SouthWestern Medical100 West Balor Ave','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','100 W Balor Ave','SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave'),
    ('1243636','SIRI SYSTEMS','15 BRAD ROAD','WEXFORD','PA','15090','','','','','','','15 BRAD RD',''),
    ('1152482','FLEETWOOD MACK','22 WINDSOCK CT','ADDISON','IL','60101','','PO BOX 951','CHICAGO','IL','60694-5124','','22 WINDSOCK CT','PO BOX 951'),
    ('1224483','Aerospace Junction','211500 Communicate Ave','Mingo Junction','OH','43939','USA','P O Box 99','Mingo Junction','OH','43939','USA','211500 Communicate Ave','PO Box 99'),
    ('1243397','Squeezy Felt','SCHREIBER DIST','NEW KENSINGTON','PA','15068','','','','','','','SCHREIBER DIST',''),
    ('1230895','NERO CO','28 North US State Highway 99','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','PO Box 204','Cape Girardeau','MO','63702-2045','USA','28 N US State Hwy 99','PO Box 204'),
    ('1243782','NERO CO','28 North US State Highway 99','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','PO Box 204','Cape Girardeau','MO','63702-2045','USA','28 N US State Hwy 99','PO Box 204'),
    ('1135880','RICHARD PRYOR SEMINARS','PO BOX 2194','KANSAS CITY','MO','64121-9468','USA','RICHARD PRYOR SEMINARS P O BOX 2194','KANSAS CITY','MO','64121-9468','USA','PO BOX 2194','RICHARD PRYOR SEMINARS PO BOX 2194'),
    ('1241328','INFINITY AND BEYOND','P.O. BOX 169','GASTONIA','NC','28053-0269','USA','','','','','','PO BOX 169',''),
    ('1259522','ZEEBO INC','PO BOX 169','GASSTONIA','NC','28053-0269','USA','','','','','','PO BOX 169',''),
    ('1255253','AT&T','PO Box 50221','Carol Stream','IL','60197','USA','','','','','','PO Box 50221',''),
    ('1135513','AT&T','PO Box 50221','Carol Stream','IL','60197-5080','USA','','','','','','PO Box 50221',''),
    ('1119161','Machine Co, Inc','3306 N Thorne Blvd','Chattanooga','TN','','','PO BOX 5301','CHATTANOOGA','TN','37406','USA','3306 N Thorne Blvd','PO BOX 5301'),
    ('1176587','Topsy Turvy','365 Welmington Road','Chicago','IL','60606','USA','','','','','','365 Welmington Rd',''),
    ('2156671','Topsy Turvvy, Inc.','P.O. Box 55217','Columbus','OH','43081','','365 Welmington Road','Chicago','IL','60606','USA','','365 Welmington Rd')


CREATE TABLE [dupe_addresses](
    [NewAdd] [varchar](255) NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dupe_addresses] VALUES
    ('100 W Balor Ave'),
    ('28 N US State Hwy 99'),
    ('365 Welmington Rd'),
    ('PO BOX 169'),
    ('PO Box 204'),
    ('PO Box 50221'),
    ('SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave')
```

Existing Query:

```
INSERT INTO [dupecheck]
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        'Address Match' AS [Reason], 
        pv.[Supplier_No], 
        pv.[Name], 
        pv.[Address], 
        pv.[City], 
        pv.[State], 
        pv.[Zip], 
        pv.[Country], 
        pv.[Remit_Address], 
        pv.[Remit_City], 
        pv.[Remit_State], 
        pv.[Remit_Zip], 
        pv.[Remit_Country]
         FROM [dupe_addresses] n 
      LEFT JOIN [sample_data] pv 
        ON 
        (n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanAddress] AND ( [Address] <> '' AND [Address] IS NOT NULL ) )
       WHERE ([Supplier_No] IS NOT NULL AND [Supplier_No] <> '') 

    UNION

    SELECT 
        'Address Match' AS [Reason], 
        pv.[Supplier_No], 
        pv.[Name], 
        pv.[Address], 
        pv.[City], 
        pv.[State], 
        pv.[Zip], 
        pv.[Country], 
        pv.[Remit_Address], 
        pv.[Remit_City], 
        pv.[Remit_State], 
        pv.[Remit_Zip], 
        pv.[Remit_Country]
         FROM [dupe_addresses] n 
      LEFT JOIN [sample_data] pv 
        ON 
        (n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanRemit_Address] AND ( [Remit_Address] <> '' AND [Remit_Address] IS NOT NULL) )
       WHERE ([Supplier_No] IS NOT NULL AND [Supplier_No] <> '') 
       ) q1
```

Current Results:

```
Reason  Supplier_No Name    Address City    State   Zip Country Remit_Address   Remit_City  Remit_State Remit_Zip   Remit_Country
Address Match   1135513 AT&T    PO Box 50221    Carol Stream    IL  60197-5080  USA                 
Address Match   1176587 Topsy Turvy 365 Welmington Road Chicago IL  60606   USA                 
Address Match   1218409 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave Osceola AR  72370   USA
Address Match   1230895 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1241328 INFINITY AND BEYOND P.O. BOX 169    GASTONIA    NC  28053-0269  USA                 
Address Match   1243782 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1243789 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA
Address Match   1255253 AT&T    PO Box 50221    Carol Stream    IL  60197   USA                 
Address Match   1259522 ZEEBO INC   PO BOX 169  GASSTONIA   NC  28053-0269  USA                 
Address Match   2156671 Topsy Turvvy, Inc.  P.O. Box 55217  Columbus    OH  43081       365 Welmington Road Chicago IL  60606   USA
```

Desired Results:

```
Reason  Supplier_No Name    Address City    State   Zip Country Remit_Address   Remit_City  Remit_State Remit_Zip   Remit_Country   rank
Address Match   1135513 AT&T    PO Box 50221    Carol Stream    IL  60197-5080  USA                     1
Address Match   1255253 AT&T    PO Box 50221    Carol Stream    IL  60197   USA                     1
Address Match   1241328 INFINITY AND BEYOND P.O. BOX 169    GASTONIA    NC  28053-0269  USA                     2
Address Match   1259522 ZEEBO INC   PO BOX 169  GASSTONIA   NC  28053-0269  USA                     2
Address Match   1243782 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA 3
Address Match   1230895 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA 3
Address Match   1218409 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave Osceola AR  72370   USA 4
Address Match   1243789 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA 4
Address Match   2156671 Topsy Turvvy, Inc.  P.O. Box 55217  Columbus    OH  43081       365 Welmington Road Chicago IL  60606   USA 5
Address Match   1176587 Topsy Turvy 365 Welmington Road Chicago IL  60606   USA                     5
```

Comment: Upvoted for the level of details.

Comment: Add a [NewAdd] column to [dupecheck] table and use it for sorting/ranking

Comment: Is number of row OK?

Comment: @Serg But what goes in the NewAdd field?  `[cleanAddress]` or `[cleanRemit_Address] ` that is the same issue I have with the `ORDER BY`
If I add it in each of the SELECTS then NERO would have a match on `[cleanAddress]` and ANOTHER on `[cleanRemit_Address]`.  I use the UNION to remove those duplicates, but adding another field will mess that up.
Crap, the RANK might pose a similar issue.  I'm banging my head here!

Comment: Really, your sample data has 14 matches which are reduced to 10 by `UNION`. Looks like this way some info is lost preventing proper grouping.

Comment: What last 4 rows of the Desired Results have in common so they are assigne the same rank=4?

Comment: Upvote for level of details(2).

Comment: It looks like you want to sort by the third column, `address`.  Why doesn't that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query creates the desired result.

```
with cte as (
    select s2.NewAdd grp, s1.*
        , rank() over(partition by Supplier_No order by s2.NewAdd) rnk
    from sample_data s1
    inner join dupe_addresses s2 on  
        (s1.cleanAddress=s2.newAdd) or (s1.cleanRemit_Address=s2.newAdd)
)
select c1.*
from cte c1
where rnk = 1
order by c1.grp
```

removed the Union , and combine two join Conditions by  `OR`  instead.
so a record with both conditions may be found.

The `rank()` is used to calculate a rank for each row within a partition of a result set.

`partition by Supplier_No` used to To identify duplicate records.

finally, use the `where rnk = 1` to see the group of records without repetition.

Comment: That is a MUCH cleaner JOIN that what I have, but still doesn't group the matched records together.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean, please explain more about the issue

Comment: Your answer gives me the exact same as my "Current Results".  AT&T is in the data twice using the same address but diff vendor numbers.  When you view the output one record is on line 1, and the other is on line 8.
If you look at the "Desired Results" you can see all of them are grouped together.  "Infinity and Beyond" and "Zeebo" also have the same address, so if they aren't grouped and it's sorted by name or address then the records could be separated by a huge number, making evaluation very difficult and time consuming.

Comment: I'm edited the code, this new code also does grouping.
(Some records match both fields and in two Group, if you want to see them too, should be remove  `where rnk=1` )

Comment: @RezaBasereh for a good quality answer please actually explain what it does as well as adding working code.

Comment: This works great, thank you!  As @DaleK suggested some explanation would be nice to help someone else who might have a similar question.  I know I learned a lot of the years looking at other people's questions and answers :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a shorter/cleaner way to do this but while I wait for my coffee to kick in the below should do what you want.

```
SELECT s1.*
    ,coalesce((
            SELECT s1.Cleanaddress
            FROM dupe_addresses s2
            WHERE s1.cleanAddress = s2.newAdd
            ), (
            SELECT s1.cleanRemit_Address
            FROM dupe_addresses s2
            WHERE s1.cleanRemit_Address = s2.newAdd
            )) AS MatchedAddress
FROM sample_data s1
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dupe_addresses s2
        WHERE (s1.cleanAddress = s2.newAdd)
            OR (s1.cleanRemit_Address = s2.newAdd)
        )
ORDER BY MatchedAddress
```

Edit:  I've thought about this a bit more.  I would change the way your doing this since you say you have more criteria for matching this would be a better way of achieving what you want.  Basically I would create a CleanedAddressID on your supplier/data table and then put all your cleaned addresses into a cleaned address table.

Once you've done that you can update the CleanedAddressID and you can use more criteria/matching than you are currently using.

The following code should help you out and the final query will return all your duplicates based on address.

As time goes on you could add different matches in a similar way and then create a duplication score.  I know that's outside the context of your question but I thought I'd mention it since it shows how this more dynamic solution makes it easier to expand upon.

I've left the above solution is as you said this did what you want and I'll let you digest it but it's messy and would get messier with more criteria.

```
CREATE TABLE [CleanedAddresses] (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,[Address] [varchar](255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    ,PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    )

INSERT INTO [CleanedAddresses] ([Address])
VALUES ('100 W Balor Ave')
    ,('28 N US State Hwy 99')
    ,('365 Welmington Rd')
    ,('PO BOX 169')
    ,('PO Box 204')
    ,('PO Box 50221')
    ,('SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave')

CREATE TABLE [sample_data] (
    [Supplier_No] VARCHAR(255)
    ,[Name] VARCHAR(255)
    ,[Address] VARCHAR(255)
    ,[City] VARCHAR(255)
    ,[State] VARCHAR(255)
    ,[Zip] VARCHAR(255)
    ,[Country] VARCHAR(255)
    ,[Remit_Address] VARCHAR(255)
    ,[Remit_City] VARCHAR(255)
    ,[Remit_State] VARCHAR(255)
    ,[Remit_Zip] VARCHAR(255)
    ,[Remit_Country] VARCHAR(255)
    ,[cleanAddress] VARCHAR(255)
    ,[cleanRemit_Address] VARCHAR(255)
    ,CleanAddressID INT NULL CONSTRAINT [suppliers_pk] PRIMARY KEY ([Supplier_No])
    ,FOREIGN KEY (CleanAddressID) REFERENCES [CleanedAddresses](ID)
    )

INSERT INTO [sample_data] (
    [Supplier_No]
    ,[Name]
    ,[Address]
    ,[City]
    ,[State]
    ,[Zip]
    ,[Country]
    ,[Remit_Address]
    ,[Remit_City]
    ,[Remit_State]
    ,[Remit_Zip]
    ,[Remit_Country]
    ,[cleanAddress]
    ,[cleanRemit_Address]
    )
VALUES (
    '1039104'
    ,'Geez Companies'
    ,'100 Aero Hudson Rd'
    ,'Streetsboro'
    ,'OH'
    ,'44241'
    ,''
    ,'100 Aero Hudson Road'
    ,'Streetsboro'
    ,'OH'
    ,'44241'
    ,'USA'
    ,'100 Aero Hudson Rd'
    ,'100 Aero Hudson Rd'
    )
    ,(
    '1218409'
    ,'SouthWestern Medical'
    ,'100 West Balor Ave'
    ,'Osceola'
    ,'AR'
    ,'72370'
    ,'USA'
    ,'SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave'
    ,'Osceola'
    ,'AR'
    ,'72370'
    ,'USA'
    ,'100 W Balor Ave'
    ,'SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave'
    )
    ,(
    '1243789'
    ,'SouthWestern Medical'
    ,'100 West Balor Ave'
    ,'Osceola'
    ,'AR'
    ,'72370'
    ,'USA'
    ,'SouthWestern Medical100 West Balor Ave'
    ,'Osceola'
    ,'AR'
    ,'72370'
    ,'USA'
    ,'100 W Balor Ave'
    ,'SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave'
    )
    ,(
    '1243636'
    ,'SIRI SYSTEMS'
    ,'15 BRAD ROAD'
    ,'WEXFORD'
    ,'PA'
    ,'15090'
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,'15 BRAD RD'
    ,''
    )
    ,(
    '1152482'
    ,'FLEETWOOD MACK'
    ,'22 WINDSOCK CT'
    ,'ADDISON'
    ,'IL'
    ,'60101'
    ,''
    ,'PO BOX 951'
    ,'CHICAGO'
    ,'IL'
    ,'60694-5124'
    ,''
    ,'22 WINDSOCK CT'
    ,'PO BOX 951'
    )
    ,(
    '1224483'
    ,'Aerospace Junction'
    ,'211500 Communicate Ave'
    ,'Mingo Junction'
    ,'OH'
    ,'43939'
    ,'USA'
    ,'P O Box 99'
    ,'Mingo Junction'
    ,'OH'
    ,'43939'
    ,'USA'
    ,'211500 Communicate Ave'
    ,'PO Box 99'
    )
    ,(
    '1243397'
    ,'Squeezy Felt'
    ,'SCHREIBER DIST'
    ,'NEW KENSINGTON'
    ,'PA'
    ,'15068'
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,'SCHREIBER DIST'
    ,''
    )
    ,(
    '1230895'
    ,'NERO CO'
    ,'28 North US State Highway 99'
    ,'Osceola'
    ,'AR'
    ,'72370'
    ,'USA'
    ,'PO Box 204'
    ,'Cape Girardeau'
    ,'MO'
    ,'63702-2045'
    ,'USA'
    ,'28 N US State Hwy 99'
    ,'PO Box 204'
    )
    ,(
    '1243782'
    ,'NERO CO'
    ,'28 North US State Highway 99'
    ,'Osceola'
    ,'AR'
    ,'72370'
    ,'USA'
    ,'PO Box 204'
    ,'Cape Girardeau'
    ,'MO'
    ,'63702-2045'
    ,'USA'
    ,'28 N US State Hwy 99'
    ,'PO Box 204'
    )
    ,(
    '1135880'
    ,'RICHARD PRYOR SEMINARS'
    ,'PO BOX 2194'
    ,'KANSAS CITY'
    ,'MO'
    ,'64121-9468'
    ,'USA'
    ,'RICHARD PRYOR SEMINARS P O BOX 2194'
    ,'KANSAS CITY'
    ,'MO'
    ,'64121-9468'
    ,'USA'
    ,'PO BOX 2194'
    ,'RICHARD PRYOR SEMINARS PO BOX 2194'
    )
    ,(
    '1241328'
    ,'INFINITY AND BEYOND'
    ,'P.O. BOX 169'
    ,'GASTONIA'
    ,'NC'
    ,'28053-0269'
    ,'USA'
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,'PO BOX 169'
    ,''
    )
    ,(
    '1259522'
    ,'ZEEBO INC'
    ,'PO BOX 169'
    ,'GASSTONIA'
    ,'NC'
    ,'28053-0269'
    ,'USA'
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,'PO BOX 169'
    ,''
    )
    ,(
    '1255253'
    ,'AT&T'
    ,'PO Box 50221'
    ,'Carol Stream'
    ,'IL'
    ,'60197'
    ,'USA'
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,'PO Box 50221'
    ,''
    )
    ,(
    '1135513'
    ,'AT&T'
    ,'PO Box 50221'
    ,'Carol Stream'
    ,'IL'
    ,'60197-5080'
    ,'USA'
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,'PO Box 50221'
    ,''
    )
    ,(
    '1119161'
    ,'Machine Co, Inc'
    ,'3306 N Thorne Blvd'
    ,'Chattanooga'
    ,'TN'
    ,''
    ,''
    ,'PO BOX 5301'
    ,'CHATTANOOGA'
    ,'TN'
    ,'37406'
    ,'USA'
    ,'3306 N Thorne Blvd'
    ,'PO BOX 5301'
    )
    ,(
    '1176587'
    ,'Topsy Turvy'
    ,'365 Welmington Road'
    ,'Chicago'
    ,'IL'
    ,'60606'
    ,'USA'
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,'365 Welmington Rd'
    ,''
    )
    ,(
    '2156671'
    ,'Topsy Turvvy, Inc.'
    ,'P.O. Box 55217'
    ,'Columbus'
    ,'OH'
    ,'43081'
    ,''
    ,'365 Welmington Road'
    ,'Chicago'
    ,'IL'
    ,'60606'
    ,'USA'
    ,''
    ,'365 Welmington Rd'
    )

UPDATE S
SET CleanAddressID = c.ID
FROM Sample_data S
INNER JOIN CleanedAddresses C ON c.Address = s.cleanAddress

UPDATE S
SET CleanAddressID = c.ID
FROM Sample_data S
INNER JOIN CleanedAddresses C ON c.Address = s.cleanRemit_Address
WHERE s.CleanAddressID IS NULL

SELECT *
FROM Sample_data S
WHERE CleanAddressID IS NOT NULL
    AND cleanAddressID IN (
        SELECT s2.cleanAddressID
        FROM sample_data s2
        GROUP BY s2.cleanAddressID
        HAVING count(*) > 1
        )
ORDER BY CleanAddressID
```

Comment: That does give me what I want!  I'm going to need to spend some time with it to understand it so I can scale it up and additional address fields to the mix :D  It's way late/early so I'll circle back at the crack of noon tomorrow when I get up :D

Comment: This will get messy the more ways you make matches. I assume you are trying to match against all records to find duplicates.  
I would suggest creating a table called say CleanedAddresses and then processing all of your addresses through whatever you have as a cleaner and inserting a distinct list of them into the table CleanedAddresses with an Identity column as the PK.  Then you can perform various joins to that CleanedAddresses table and then ORDER BY the ID on CleanedAddresses.  That's going to be  much cleaner and efficient.

Comment: I actually am doing a lot of what you suggest.  The sample data has the cleaned address.  The Biggest issue is that some records have 2-3 addresses, and those addresses have 1-3 address lines.  So I can't have ONE cleaned address field, I may have 9, and I need to check against all of them.  The `[dupe_addresses]` table in my question is the same as your `[CleanedAddresses]`.  I'm just getting MY coffee and I'll sit down with this and look it over.

Comment: Good to hear you're already going down that line.  My suggestion would still stand that you add a new column and update it.  You can call it DupeaddressID if you like for clarity.  

If you could have multiple duplicates based on different criteria you could have an intermediate many to many table.

Create Table Duplicates(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key, SupplierID, DuplicateAddressID)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can avoid using of expensive `union` by mentioning both the condition in `on clause` like below:

```
  ON 
  (n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanAddress] AND ( [Address] <> '' AND [Address] IS NOT NULL ) )
  or 
  (n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanRemit_Address] AND ( [Remit_Address] <> '' AND [Remit_Address] IS NOT NULL) )
```

Then you can remove duplicate rows per supplier_no with the help of row_number()over() window function.

Then rank those rows according to their addreses with

```
dense_rank()over(order by case when(n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanAddress] AND ( [Address] < '' AND [Address] IS NOT NULL ) )
             then cleanaddress else Remit_Address end)
```

But I could not understand how you formed group 4 with four rows.

Query:

```
 with cte 
 as
 (
     SELECT 
         'Address Match' AS [Reason], 
         pv.[Supplier_No], 
         pv.[Name], 
         pv.[Address], 
         pv.[City], 
         pv.[State], 
         pv.[Zip], 
         pv.[Country], 
         pv.[Remit_Address], 
         pv.[Remit_City], 
         pv.[Remit_State], 
         pv.[Remit_Zip], 
         pv.[Remit_Country],
         row_number()over (partition by supplier_no order by address  ,remit_address )rn,
         dense_rank()over(order by case when(n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanAddress] AND ( [Address] < '' AND [Address] IS NOT NULL ) )
         then cleanaddress else Remit_Address end) rnk
          FROM [dupe_addresses] n 
       LEFT JOIN [sample_data] pv 
         ON 
         (n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanAddress] AND ( [Address] < '' AND [Address] IS NOT NULL ) )
         or 
          (n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanRemit_Address] AND ( [Remit_Address] < '' AND [Remit_Address] IS NOT NULL) )
        WHERE [Supplier_No] IS NOT NULL AND [Supplier_No] < ''
 )
 select * from cte where rn=1
 order by rnk desc
```

| Reason | Supplier_No | Name | Address | City | State | Zip | Country | Remit_Address | Remit_City | Remit_State | Remit_Zip | Remit_Country | rn | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Address Match | 1135513 | AT&T | PO Box 50221 | Carol Stream | IL | 60197-5080 | USA |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 7 |
| Address Match | 1255253 | AT&T | PO Box 50221 | Carol Stream | IL | 60197 | USA |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 7 |
| Address Match | 1259522 | ZEEBO INC | PO BOX 169 | GASSTONIA | NC | 28053-0269 | USA |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 5 |
| Address Match | 1241328 | INFINITY AND BEYOND | P.O. BOX 169 | GASTONIA | NC | 28053-0269 | USA |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 5 |
| Address Match | 2156671 | Topsy Turvvy, Inc. | P.O. Box 55217 | Columbus | OH | 43081 |  | 365 Welmington Road | Chicago | IL | 60606 | USA | 1 | 4 |
| Address Match | 1176587 | Topsy Turvy | 365 Welmington Road | Chicago | IL | 60606 | USA |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 3 |
| Address Match | 1230895 | NERO CO | 28 North US State Highway 99 | Osceola | AR | 72370 | USA | PO Box 204 | Cape Girardeau | MO | 63702-2045 | USA | 1 | 2 |
| Address Match | 1243782 | NERO CO | 28 North US State Highway 99 | Osceola | AR | 72370 | USA | PO Box 204 | Cape Girardeau | MO | 63702-2045 | USA | 1 | 2 |
| Address Match | 1218409 | SouthWestern Medical | 100 West Balor Ave | Osceola | AR | 72370 | USA | SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave | Osceola | AR | 72370 | USA | 1 | 1 |
| Address Match | 1243789 | SouthWestern Medical | 100 West Balor Ave | Osceola | AR | 72370 | USA | SouthWestern Medical100 West Balor Ave | Osceola | AR | 72370 | USA | 1 | 1 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a5108453e22e63160710c6d5fe632f33)*

Comment: Good catch on group 4, that was an unfortunate copy/paste error.  I have corrected it, the last two are group 5.  I was using cte and row number to remove the dupes, but I couldn't wrap my head around how to add rank as well.  Both CTE and the row number confuse me, so I struggle with them a bit :D

Comment: I'll spend some time with this to see how it works against my larger data set.  It looks as though this might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Best of luck. Please let me know if you face any difficulties.

Comment: On my larger dataset (approx 100k records) it gives me the right # of records, but the ranking is off.  It looks like it's the same problem I had when the `[cleanAddress]` of one record matched the `[cleanRemit_Address]` field in another record.

Comment: Reza's gives me the correct ranking and # of records.  Thank you for your detailed answer, I have saved it to reference for row and rank in the future!

Comment: That's great. Best wishes.